# Datagrip auto rollback on error

Tags: rollback, datagrip

Not sure if I am asking the right question, but here goes...

I am connected to postgres instance with auto commit turned off. What I am seeing is that if there is a syntax issue with a query:

```
select * fro table limit 400
```

, I have to first rollback before I can select again. If I don't I get the following error message:

> "ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction block"

Is there anywhere I can set to "auto rollback"

Maybe I am just using it incorrectly?

Comment: Hello! We at JetBrains know about this issue. Auto-rollback perhaps is not the best way — imagine if you have a huge script and the error is in the middle. I think we should use rollback to savepoint: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-rollback-to.html Please, watch'n'vote this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2696

Comment: @moscas The other issue, perhaps related to this is when a query is stopped midway, subsequent queries to same table results in a java.EOF exception. When I then use a different IDE and select from the table the error in datagrip changes to a stackoverflow error... After I type in rollback and execute everything goes back to normal... weird

Comment: What do you mean by another IDE? Jetbrains IDE? Or third-party? About crashing queries, please vote and watch this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1697 perhaps it is the same.

Comment: Sql Workbench J to be precise. So at the moment I cannot select from a specific table in Datagrip (java.io.EOFException), but I can select from the table in Workbench... Annoying

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue any more. Just check out the latest DataGrip version
[image: cancel]